# Javascript (Jquery) detect orientation change on Microsoft Surface

Tags: rotation, surface

I'm trying to detect orientation change on Microsoft Surface. I tried to bind 'orientationchange', 'resize' event but it not working on Microsoft Surface (Ipad and other tablet working fine). Any idea for it?

Comment: up. any one here?